# jquery capture generated css?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a little css/javascript toy where sliders give the user control over the css properties of elements on the screen. I was thinking that there might be a way in jQuery to extract the current styles of an element - I know that I can access them independently by doing something like

```
$("#foo").css("bar")
```

But it would be great if I could get at all of the styles applied to an object in one fell swoop. Possible? (Dumb idea?)

Comment: It's definitely possible, have you tried any of the answers, yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's inline CSS, you could use this:

```
$("#element").attr("style");
```

And to go above and beyond:

```
var str   = $("#element").attr("style");
var style = str.split(";");
for(i=0;i<=style.length;i++){
    alert(style[i]);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/5hNrL/).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the currently set inline styles for an element like this:

```
$("#foo").attr("style");
```

Of course you'd have to parse that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Given the hypothetical mark-up:

```
<span id="test">Some content of 'test'</span>
<pre id="css"></pre>
```

It's certainly possible, though apparently quite tortuous:

```
$('#test').css({'background-color':'red','color':'white','display':'block'});
var $elem = $('#test');
var styles = document.getElementById('test').style;
var prop;

for(var i=0;i<styles.length;i++){
    prop = $elem[0].style[styles[i]];
    console.log(styles[i] + ': ' + prop);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Bzm7h/).

Revised and (slightly) refined version of the above:

```
$('#test').css({'background-color':'red','color':'white','display':'block'});

var elem = document.getElementById('test');
var styles = document.getElementById('test').style;
var prop;

if (styles.length){
    $('#css').append('<ul></ul>');
    for(var i=0;i<styles.length;i++){
        prop = elem.style[styles[i]];
        $('<li />').text(styles[i] + ': ' + prop + ';').appendTo('#css ul');
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Bzm7h/1/).

The above essentially parses the in-line styles of the element, since that's where jQuery (and JavaScript as a whole) makes its effects known. It is possible to access the `window.getComputedStyle()`, but that seems a little more than you'd need, since so far as I can tell you want to show the CSS created by the tools on your page.